# Dependency Injected Repository Pattern object gets disposed after asyn call

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, async-await, asp.net-web-api2, autofac

I am making a PostAsync call within the business layer of my WebAPI application.

Using AutoFac I am setting up my bindings like this:

```
builder.RegisterGeneric(typeof(SqlServerRepository<>))
       .As(typeof(IRepository<>))
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
builder.RegisterType<WspSQLDbContext>()
       .As<DbContext>()
       .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

The repository is injected into the controller:

```
public KenSciConnector(log4net.ILog logger, IRepository<KenSciBatch> kensciBatchRepository) {
    _logger = logger;
    _kensciBatchRepository = kensciBatchRepository;
}
```

The function which makes the call to the async function looks like this:

```
public Response SendToVendor(Observation observation) {
    Response batchingResponse;
    // some logic
    var sendResponse = SendToKensci(requestObject, batch);           
    return batchingResponse;
}
```

...and the function which actually makes the async call look like this:

```
private async Task<Response> SendToKensci(KenSciRequest requestObject, KenSciBatch kenSciBatch) {
    var response = new Response();

    try {
        var httpClient = new HttpClient();

        await httpClient
            .PostAsync(httpClient.BaseAddress, new StringContent(seralizedObject, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"))
            .ContinueWith((requestTask) => UpdateBatch(requestTask, kenSciBatch));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // some logic
            return response;
        }

        // some logic
        return response;
    }
```

In the callback function when I try to update, I get an exception that the `DbContext` has already been disposed.

```
private void UpdateBatch(Task<HttpResponseMessage> requestTask, KenSciBatch kenSciBatch) {
    try {
        if (requestTask.Result.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK) {
            kenSciBatch.Status = BatchStatus.Sent;
            _kensciBatchRepository.Update(kenSciBatch);
        }
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        throw ex;
    }
}
```

Comment: yes that was the problem. put is as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here:

```
var sendResponse = SendToKensci(requestObject, batch);
```

you don't await `SendToKensci` (which returns `Task`), and so sometimes in the middle of it's execution - context is disposed (because you left `SendToVendor` function already)